# How can I pass the instance of an object through a multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, pipe, pickle, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I'm writing a library that essentially is an engine for HTTP responses (similar to Flask or DJango). The problem is that I'm currently trying to adapt the code so that it runs in it's own Process so it can be shut down at any time. The problem is that I'm unable to do so as the function I need to call is a method on an instance of a class called `Server`. From my research, the problem is that it is unable to pickle the object, and that's why I'm getting the error I'm getting. I can't figure out any other way to pass the object, or calling static methods, because the method accesses other methods to primarily get route data. I'm very new to the multiprocessing module, though I do have quite a lot of experience with the similar threading module.

Here's the current code for the `Server` class. I implemented a thread to handle logging because, it is my understanding that it's impossible to pass logging objects through processes. So I used queues to solve it.

```
import threading
import multiprocessing
import socket
import logging
from typing import Self

from . import request
from . import routes

class Server(routes.Routes):
    '''HTTP server running on a specified host and port.'''

    def __init__(self,
                 *,
                 host: str = '127.0.0.1',
                 port: int = 80,
                 logger: logging.Logger = None) -> None:
        '''Initializes the server class.'''
        
        super().__init__()
        
        self._host: str = host

        self._port: int = port

        self._logger: logging.Logger = logger

        if self._logger:

            self._logging_queue: multiprocessing.Queue = multiprocessing.Queue(-1)

        self._process: multiprocessing.Process = \
multiprocessing.Process(target = self._listen,
                        daemon = True)

    def start(self) -> None:
        '''Starts the server. Specify the host and port to listen on.
        Optionally, specify a logging.Logger object to log to.'''
        
        self._process.start()

        if self._logger:

            threading.Thread(target = self._logging_handler,
                            daemon = True).start()
        
    def wait(self) -> None:
        '''Waits for a keyboard interrupt or the enter key is pressed is recieved.'''

        try:

            input('Press Enter to continue...')

        except (KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError):

            pass

    def stop(self) -> None:
        '''Stops the server.'''

        if self._logger:

            self._logging_queue.put((logging.INFO,
                                     'Exiting server...'))

        self._process.kill()

    def _listen(self) -> None:
        '''Listens for incoming connections 
        and spawns a thread to handle each request.'''

        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:

            s.bind((self._host, self._port))

            s.listen()

            if self._logger:

                self._logging_queue.put((logging.INFO, f'Server hosted on \
{self._host}:{self._port}.'))

            while True:

                connection, address = s.accept()

                threading.Thread(target = self._handle_request,
                                kwargs = {'connection': connection,
                                        'address': address},
                                daemon = True).start()
                
    def _handle_request(self,
                        connection: socket.socket,
                        address: socket.AddressInfo) -> None:
        '''Handles a request from a client.'''

        while True:
            
            try:

                raw_request = ''

                while True:

                    raw_request += connection.recv(4096).decode(encoding = 'utf-8',
                                                                errors = 'ignore')

                    if '\r\n\r\n' in raw_request or raw_request == '':

                        break

                if not raw_request:
                        
                        if self._logger:

                            self._logging_queue.put((logging.DEBUG, f'Connection closed\
 by client {address[0]}:{address[1]}.'))

                        connection.close()

                        return None

                try:

                    parsed_request = request.Request.from_string(address = address,
                                                                 request = raw_request)

                except Exception:

                    if self._logger:

                        self._logging_queue.put((logging.ERROR, f'Invalid request from \
{address[0]}:{address[1]}, closing connection.'))

                    connection.close()

                    return None

                if content_length:=parsed_request.headers.get('Content-Length'):

                    if length_recieved:=len(raw_request.split('\r\n\r\n')[1]) < \
                    (length_to_recieve:=int(content_length)):

                        raw_request += connection.recv(length_to_recieve - \
                                                       length_recieved)\
                            .decode(encoding = 'utf-8',
                                    errors = 'ignore')

                        parsed_request = request.Request.from_string(address = address,
                                                                request = raw_request)
                        
                if self._logger:

                    self._logging_queue.put((logging.DEBUG, f'Recieved \
{parsed_request.method.title()} request from {address[0]}:{address[1]} for \
{parsed_request.path if parsed_request.path else "/"}'))

                connection.send(self._get_route(path = parsed_request.path,
                                                request = parsed_request))
                
                if self._logger:

                    self._logging_queue.put((logging.DEBUG, f'Sent \
{parsed_request.method} response to {address[0]}:{address[1]} for \
{parsed_request.path if parsed_request.path else "/"}'))

                if not parsed_request.headers.get('Connection') == 'keep-alive':

                    try:
                
                        connection.close()

                    except Exception:

                        pass

                    if self._logger:
                        
                        self._logging_queue.put((logging.DEBUG, f'Connection closed \
with {address[0]}:{address[1]} by server.'))

                    return None

            except Exception as e:

                if self._logger:

                    self._logging_queue.put((logging.ERROR, f'Error while handling \
request from {address[0]}:{address[1]}: "{e}".'))                   

                return None
            
    def _logging_handler(self) -> None:

        while self._process.is_alive():

            log_level, log_message = self._logging_queue.get()

            match log_level:

                case logging.DEBUG:

                    self._logger.debug(log_message)

                case logging.INFO:

                    self._logger.info(log_message)

                case logging.WARNING:

                    self._logger.warning(log_message)

                case logging.ERROR:

                    self._logger.error(log_message)

                case logging.CRITICAL:

                    self._logger.critical(log_message)

    def __enter__(self) -> Self:

        self.start()

        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback) -> None:

        self.stop()
```

Here's the `Routes` class.

```
import os

from . import response_messages
from . import response_codes
from . import response
from . import request
from . import render

class Routes:
    '''Stores, sorts, and handles a collection of routes.'''

    def __init__(self) -> None:

        self.routes: dict[str: callable] = {
            '/404': lambda request: response.Response(version = 1.1,
code = response_codes.ResponseCodes.NOT_FOUND,
message = response_messages.ResponseMessages.NOT_FOUND,
headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/html',
            'Content-Length': '202'},
body = b'''<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1 style="text-align: center;">404 Not Found</h1>

<hr>

<p style="text-align: center;">HTTP-PyServer</p>

</body>

</html>''')
    }

    def route(self,
              path: str,
              *,
              ressources: tuple[tuple[str, str]] = ()) -> callable:
        '''Adds a route to the routes dictionary.'''

        for ressource_file_path, ressource_reference_path in ressources:

            ressource_reference_path = '/' + ressource_reference_path.strip('/')

            if not os.path.exists(ressource_file_path):

                self.routes[ressource_reference_path] = \
                    lambda _: self.routes['/404'](request = request.Request())

            else:

                ressource = render.attachment(filepath = ressource_file_path)

                self.routes[ressource_reference_path] = \
                lambda _, ressource = ressource: ressource

        def callable_route(route_function):

            self.routes[path.rstrip('/')] = route_function

            return route_function
        
        return callable_route
    
    def _get_wildcard_path(self,
                           path: str,
                           *,
                           request: request.Request) -> bytes:
        '''Gets a route with wildcard values.'''
    
        for route in self.routes:

            if not len(route.split('/')) == len(path.split('/')):

                continue

            for sub_route, sub_path in zip(route.split('/'), path.split('/')):

                if (not sub_route == sub_path) \
                    and (not (sub_route.startswith('%') \
                            and sub_route.endswith('%'))):

                    break

            else:

                wildcard_values = []

                for sub_route, sub_path \
                    in zip(route.split('/'), path.split('/')):

                    if sub_route.startswith('%') and sub_route.endswith('%'):

                        wildcard_values.append(sub_path)

                message =  self.routes[route](request,
                                         *wildcard_values)
                
                if isinstance(message, str):

                    return bytes(render.text(message))
                
                elif isinstance(message, bytes):

                    return message
                
                elif isinstance(message, response.Response):

                    return bytes(message)
                
                else:

                    raise TypeError(f'Expected function for {request.path} \
to return str, bytes, or Response, got {type(message)}.')

        return self._get_route('/404', request = request)

    def _get_route(self,
                  path: str,
                  *,
                  request: request.Request = request.Request()) -> bytes:
        '''Gets a route from the routes dictionary.'''

        if path in self.routes:

            message = self.routes[path](request)

            if isinstance(message, str):

                return bytes(render.text(text = message))
            
            elif isinstance(message, bytes):

                return message
            
            elif isinstance(message, response.Response):

                return bytes(message)
            
            else:

                raise TypeError(f'Expected function for {request.path} \
to return str, bytes, or Response, got {type(message)}.')

        else:

            return self._get_wildcard_path(path = path,
                                          request = request)
```

Here's the error when I run a simple script:

```
$ py main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alexj\Desktop\Text Documents\Coding\HTTP-PyServer\src\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    with Server(logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)) as s:
  File "C:\Users\alexj\Desktop\Text Documents\Coding\HTTP-PyServer\src\server\server.py", line 223, in __enter__
    self.start()
  File "C:\Users\alexj\Desktop\Text Documents\Coding\HTTP-PyServer\src\server\server.py", line 40, in start
    self._process.start()
  File "C:\Users\alexj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\alexj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\alexj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 336, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\alexj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 94, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\alexj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'Routes.__init__.<locals>.<lambda>'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\alexj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 106, in spawn_main
    source_process = _winapi.OpenProcess(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

Comment: You need to design your object to be serializable. Have you read the pickle docs?

Comment: The problem is that I simply can't. I've tried to implement it so it can, but it relies on storing functions which thus makes it un-serializable.

Comment: Yes, but that reliance is a result of design decisions. It's within your power to change your mind about those decisions -- redirection through a lookup table, f/e (so you're storing a key used to _look up_ the correct function, but not serializing the function itself) would suffice.

Comment: Well how would I serialize the function to be pickleable.

Comment: Also I had another idea I need to test that might be able to bypass the need for multiprocessing all together. Do you know if you can close a socket in another thread and it will affect the main thread?

Comment: "serialize the function to be picklable" -- the point is, you don't; you just serialize a lookup-table key, and that can be a regular string.

Comment: That said, there _are_ alternatives -- think about using the `dill` module instead of stock `pickle`.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find a way to pickle the class and call it through multiprocessing, however I found a way to close the socket cleanly while it's listening. What I did is created one thread that ran the socket and handled requests. In the main thread, when I call socket.socket.close the socket will close even if it's listening. It has a chance to through an OS Error, but you just have to catch it. It solves all the problems and works super nicely.